# Как узнать доступное место для установки пакетов?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Мне нужен простой способ узнать сколько памяти доступно для установки через apt-get, ведь известно что он устанавливает пакет с полным списком зависимостей, а на все может памяти и не хватить.

Comment: непонятно, при чём тут память. вероятно, речь о свободном месте на примонтированных файловых системах. посмотреть его можно, как и обычно, с помощью программы `df`.

Comment: Ну так перед установкой тебе сообщают скока надо скачать, сколько на винте займёт после распаковки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а какой раздел смотреть?